# Programatically detect if an audio file is stereo or mono?

Tags: audio, m4a

I am wanting to write a bash script on a MacOS platform that will perform different operations to `m4a` files with ALAC encoding, depending on whether they are stereo or mono. How can I go about the stereo/mono detection? Are there any tools/libraries that I can utilise? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it using https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html

```
if ffprobe -i the-audio-file.mp4 |& grep stereo; then
    echo stereo
else
    echo mono
fi
```

Works as ffprobe will output a result like this:

```
ffprobe version 3.4.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --disable-jack --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'the-audio-file.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A 
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: M4A mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2018-01-27T18:53:31.000000Z
    track           : 0
    disc            : 0
  Duration: 04:59:13.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 381 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: alac (alac / 0x63616C61), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 381 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-01-27T18:53:31.000000Z
       0       0       0
```

Note, this does not work for he-aac, due to [this bug in ffprobe](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3361)

Comment: @FlavienB. You need to provide more details, as I use it every week and works fine. What codec are you detecting on? Can you upload a sample?

Comment: the `&` after the pipe `|`, is it required? It throws an error for me : ```./stereo_or_mono.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `&'

./stereo_or_mono.sh: line 3: `if ffprobe -i $audio_file |& grep stereo; then'```

Comment: @aspiring1 do `bash -il` to open an interactive bash login shell, then do the command again

Comment: It worked, thanks! Could you also explain why does this happen.

Comment: @aspiring1 your terminal shell must be something other than bash, as such does does not support the bash syntax

Comment: Yeah, I actually have to use `zshrc -il` - since, I have **zsh** shell installed  - but that does support bash syntax, I guess?